# How to check intersection between rectangle and TextureRegion LibGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx, collision-detection

I don't know if it's possible, but I want to check it like this because I'm using some animated elements and some non animated elements. I was wondering how I would go about doing this. Thanks.

Comment: You must create a Rectangle around your TextureRegion and then test intersection between this Rectangle and the other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using another rectangle as a hit box that I set to the same moving coordinates as my TextureRegion.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Box2D you would create 2 bodies and trigger an event when there is a contact between the two.
One would be a Dynamic body and the other one would be a StaticBody.

more information  here> https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Box2d

Comment: I wasn't using Box2D, but that's for your reply! I figured it out.